# How to measure secondary of CT with Hall effect sensor

Tags: microcontroller, adc, current-measurement

I need to measure the current of a wire using a microcontroller.
I was given a 100A/5A CT and now I'm looking into how to measure the secondary.
I found an [ACS712 module](https://www.makerfabs.com/acs712-current-sensor-20a.html)  but I'm not sure how to connect it.

Do I need a burden resistor as in the first picture or can I connect it as in the second one?

[image: With burden resistor]
[image: Without burden resistor]

Comment: Just connect IP+ to IP-, ditch the AC712, and take the output voltage across R1.

Comment: Are you actually going to be measuring 100A? A 100:1 CT or 200:1 CT instead of 20:1 would allow you to get rid of the hall effect entirely.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### How to measure secondary of CT with an MCU A/D

Either of the offered schematics would work for using an ACS712 sensor. Adding the burden resistor would not impact the readings at all, but it is not required.

However, given that you have a 5A CT, the ACS712 will not provide a very good span of the A/D input range of your MCU.
The ACS712 provides the following output voltage range using 5A maximum input:
[image]

Notice that you will only use about 40% of the A/D range (assuming it's 0-5V) @5A secondary current. The one advantage of this configuration is that you cannot over volt the A/D input, and you do have to consider what will happen if you have a surge on the input. For example what would happen if you had a fault on you input and it was to draw 30A in the secondary for a short period before a breaker interrupted the main current?

You may be better with something along these lines:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fPnKiC.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

The TLV6001 is rated for rail-rail operation and so allows the full range of MCU or A/D input ...in addition it is rated to carry 10mA in the input protection diodes. This would allow the configuration shown to withstand voltages of +/-200 V on the input resistor R2.
You can set the burden resistor to supply whatever full scale input you require, and the input is very tolerant of over voltage.

Since the TLV600 is powered by the MCU +5 V supply it cannot produce an output voltage above 5 V or below 0 V, so the input is accurately clamped WITHOUT impacting the A/D range at all.

Answer (score 2):

> *Do I need a burden resistor as in the first picture or can I connect
> it as in the second one?*

You can connect it as in the second picture because the ACS712 has a very low input impedance. You only need a burden resistor if you want to measure the voltage across the burden due to the secondary current in the CT. A CT output will happily run into a short circuit.

Of course, you don't need to use an ACS712 if you use a low resistance burden resistor. Just an op-amp circuit is needed to do that if cost is an issue.

Or... ditch the CT and use the ACS712 directly because that's what it is intended for: -

[image]

If you are considering going for the ACS712 and powering the isolated side you might just as well feed your AC/DC power line through the low impedance input and dump the CT (one less error in your measurement).